# TO CNAR function in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have wrote one exam. i got below questions. When I execute the below statement in oracle I am getting "missing expression error".

Examples:

```
A. SELECT TO CNAR(2000, '$#,###.##') FROM dual;
B. SELECT TO CNAR(2000, '$9,999.99') FROM dual;
C. SELECT TO CNAR(2000, '$2,000.00') FROM dual;
D. SELECT TO CNAR(2000, '$N,NNN.NN') FROM dual;
```

Any one having idea about this pre defined function.

Comment: yup, i got the same questions

Comment: is that to_char or to cnar

Comment: As far as i know there is no such function as cnar in oracle

Comment: in oracle documents too this function is not specified http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm

Comment: yes, Its an internal exam

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't mean to_char? there is no TO CNAR function in Oracle.

to_char is used to convert a data item into charachter format, so the examples above give:

```
A. Invalid number format model
B. $2,000.00
C. Invalid number format model
D. Invalid number format model
```

Comment: yes might be..i googled this questions... some of the guys got the same questions in OCP exams also...

Answer (score 0):

It should have to be a typo i cannot find a function of the name cnar

if it is to_char then second expression is the only right format....